# if I change site with local devdesktop it will not change anything with my live site?

Tags: database, acquia-dev-desktop

I am new so bare with me! I am using a local acquia dev desktop 2 beta and want to make sure if I play around with it in drupal it will not change anything with my live site.

We do not host with acquia so I am sure it wont but I want to make sure anything I do does not translate to the mysql?

Again, I am apologize if this is a newbie question. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Normally there is nothing to worry about. Some advices:

1. make sure that you are working on a local database and not producction.
2. Sanitize your database (users + passwords) or use [reroute email](https://drupal.org/project/reroute_email) to ensure that your site does not send emails from your local environment.

   ```
   drush sanitize
   ```

> Reroute email: This module intercepts all outgoing emails from a Drupal site and
>   reroutes them to a predefined configurable email address.
>
> This is useful in case where you do not want email sent from a Drupal
>   site to reach the users. For example, if you copy a live site to a
>   test site for the purpose of development, and you do not want any
>   email sent to real users of the original site. Or you want to check
>   the emails sent for uniform formatting, footers, ...etc.